# Convert string array values from URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How does one convert string array values into a Javascript array object?

```
var querystring = 'lang[]=EN&lang[]=FR&type[]=1&type[]=2';
```

Into:

```
{
    lang: ['EN', 'FR'],
    type: ['2']
}
```

Below my attempt:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(decodeURI(querystring));
let entries = params.entries();

let result = {}
for(let entry of entries) { // each 'entry' is a [key, value]
    result[entry[0]] = entry[1];
}
return result;
```

Which results in:

```
[{
    "name": "lang[]",
    "value": "EN"
}, {
    "name": "lang[]",
    "value": "FR"
}, {
    "name": "type[]",
    "value": "2"
}]
```

Comment: don't understand the expected output, `type: [1,2]` would make a little sense.

Comment: @xianshenglu "type" would be an array with IDs in it.

Comment: Why not use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string or https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs

Comment: @bart, that's not consistent with `lang: [EN, FR]`

Comment: @xianshenglu Let me update the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var querystring = 'lang[]=EN&lang[]=FR&type[]=1&type[]=2';
let params = new URLSearchParams(decodeURI(querystring));
let entries = params.entries();

let result = {}
for(let entry of entries) { // each 'entry' is a [key, value]
    var key = entry[0];
    var val = entry[1];
    if(key in result){
        result[key].push(val);
    }else{
        result[key] = [val];
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: use `var key = entry[0].replace("[]", "");` instead

Comment: Like @Mark said, this breaks query strings with parameters that are not an array.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest version would be to use a library like qs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs#parsing-arrays

```
var withArray = qs.parse('a[]=b&a[]=c');
```

ressults in

```
a: ['b', 'c']
```

Comment: I am not running Node.js

Comment: You don't have to. Its just Javascript. There's even a CDN https://cdnjs.com/libraries/qs

Answer (score 3):

You should probably test for the `[]` so your code won't break with entries not ending in `[]`. You can then slice off the `[]` so your keys don't include it:

```js
var querystring = 'lang[]=EN&lang[]=FR&type[]=1&type[]=2&test=hello';

let params = new URLSearchParams(decodeURI(querystring));
let entries = params.entries();

let result = {}
for(let entry of entries) { // each 'entry' is a [key, value]
    let [key, val] = entry
    if (key.endsWith('[]')){         // array 
      key = key.slice(0,-2);         // clean up the key
      (result[key] || (result[key] = [])).push(val)
    } else {
      result[key] = val             // normal parameter
    }
}
console.log(result)
```